# Issues with starting a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I decided to start a rails project. I went to the terminal and as usual typed in rails new blog. Instead of it completing I got this error

Installing nio4r 2.3.1 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-2.3.1/ext/nio4r
C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20181001-1392-69sdrh.rb extconf.rb

current directory: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-2.3.1/ext/nio4r
make "DESTDIR=" clean
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

current directory: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-2.3.1/ext/nio4r
make "DESTDIR="
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-2.3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/nio4r-2.3.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nio4r (2.3.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nio4r -v '2.3.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rails was resolved to 5.2.1, which depends on
    actioncable was resolved to 5.2.1, which depends on
      nio4r

Now I did install the gem file nio4r version 2.3.1 and it installed successfully. but I still received the same error message. I do not know what is causing this.

Comment: Check this thread and see if it helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38507114/9911698

Comment: Try remove your Gemfile.lock and bundle install again.