# GCC compilation error when installing Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to run `bundle install` but I'm getting the Error while trying to Install Nokogiri 1.10.3

Here is the error message from `mkmf.log`.

```
gcc -o conftest -I/home/chille/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-linux -I/home/chille/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/include/ruby-2$
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wmisleading-indentation'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wimplicit-fallthrough=0'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wduplicated-cond'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wrestrict'
```

Comment: What version of `gcc` do you have?

Comment: gcc version 5.5.0 (Homebrew gcc 5.5.0_4)

Comment: I found a error. i had a 2 gcc versions installed on my system and I just run brew unlink gcc and that solved the problem.

Comment: You might want to self-answer your question for future readers. :)

Comment: I am facing this issue as well and i did not have any gcc installed via brew but i am still facing this issue, any tips?

Comment: @DenisOmerovic Having the same issue in ubuntu 16.04. Any idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 24):

For those who do not read comments

Debian 10 users, if you find

```
 gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wduplicated-cond'
```

in mkmf.log

```
brew unlink gcc
```

is what you are looking for. I spend an hour looking for an answer and yes, i once missed the answer here, but luckily i have returned and spotted it.

Comment: And ubuntu 20.04!

Answer (score 1):

I had faced a similar issue. My default compiler did not recognise certain command line options just like you are facing.

My gcc version was 10. I could solve it by adding an older gcc version (5.5) and set it as default for the  gem installation purpose. I followed the step given in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/how-to-choose-the-default-gcc-and-g-version/26518#26518) to do so.